# Callback after $.each with animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions

So I'm running some animations to bring in some divs in my first jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.turnstile = function (options, callback) {

if (!this.length) {
    return this;
}
count = this.length;
var opts = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.turnstile.defaults, options)
var delayIt = 100;
if (opts.direction == "in") {
    opts.deg = '0deg';
    opts.trans = '0,0';
    opts.opacity = 1;
} else if (opts.direction == "out") {
    opts.deg = '-90deg';
    opts.trans = "-100px, 200px";
    opts.opacity = 0;
} else if (opts.direction == "back") {
    opts.deg = '0deg';
    opts.trans = '-2000px,0px';
    opts.opacity = 0;
} else {
    opts.deg = direction;
}
this.each(function (index) {
    delayIt += opts.delayer;
    $(this).show().delay(delayIt).transition({
        perspective: '0px',
        rotateY: opts.deg,
        opacity: opts.opacity,
        translate: opts.trans
    }, 400, 'cubic-bezier(0.33,0.66,0.66,1)', function () {
        if (opts.direction == "back" || opts.direction == "out") {
            $(this).hide();
        }
        if (!--count && callback && typeof (callback) === "function") {
            if ($(":animated").length === 0) {
                callback.call(this);
            }
        }
    });
});
return this;
};
```

Now, I'd like to call my callback when all animations are completed, which should mathematically be `(delayIt+400)*count` - but I can't get the callback to run when all of the animations are complete. As you might be able to tell from its current state, I've attempted to check for `:animated`, used the `!--count` condition, and even tried setting a timeout equal to the duration of the  animations, but all seem to fire asynchronously. What is the best way to animate these and call something back when done?

[Here's the info](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) on the `.transition()` plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested with your code (i'm not familiar with `.transition`), but try this:

```
    ...
    this.promise().done(function(){
        alert('all done');
    });
    return this;
};
```

Comment: I didn't know that you can call `.promise` on every jQuery object :) But is the callback really executed only after each animation is complete or do you have to use `$.when` somehow?

Comment: @FelixKling I'm not positive in this case. I do know if you use `$("ul > li").fadeIn(3000).promise().done(handler)` handler will get called once when they are all faded in. I'm not familiar with how this transition method works.

Comment: It worked either way - I knew about `.promise()` but wasn't sure if it was good for this use case. Thanks! Tons of headaches with this one :)

Comment: Also, added the transition plugin info just in case there's another way to accomplish this :)

Comment: Wow, that's sortof interesting that it still works using `.promise` considering that the transition plugin is using css3. It must be powered by the animation queue, or be using it in some way.

Comment: @KevinB it adds all of the anims to the animation queue.